# find the best model using cross validation

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cross-validation

I'm currently using Matlab for a project. I'm training a ensemble model for classification problem.

I split the data into `test` and `training`, and using `kfold` cross-validation `k=4` in the training data.But unlike `Scikit-learn`, the Matlab `fitcensemble` function with `kFold` parameter doesn't return the best model in cv and `kFoldPredict` function doesn't seems support predicting using the `test` data.

Is there a way to find the best model in the cross-validation? Or I have to do it manually.

---

Code

```
# X,y are test data
mdl = fitcensemble(X,y, 'KFold', 4);
# kfoldPredict doesn't support input data
yhat = kfoldPredict(mdl);
```